# Transfer executable file from Linux to mac

Tags: linux, osx, scp

I have a file which is an executable sitting on the server. When I just use `scp` to copy it down to my desktop which is a mac i get bash - ./fig up cannot execute binary file.

I believe this is because it came from linux, and now I am trying to run it on a mac terminal. Any idea how to resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `fig` is a binary, as opposed to a script, then it will not run on a different operating system. Run `file fig` to find out (if the output is something similar to `ELF 64-bit LSB executable`, then it's a binary, if it looks more like `Perl script, ASCII text executable`, then it's a script and has at least a fighting chance of running on a different platform). In this case, you will have to find a version of this program that was built for the proper platform.

Comment: Yes, this turns out to be the problem. Thank you I'll accept the answer after the time limit is up. :)